# how to execute? jquery.on event with OR when some condition is true?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-mobile

some Javascript code is to run only after certain events for example (jquery mobile):

```
$(document).on('pageinit', function(){ run code which needs an inited page. });
```

What javascript/jquery patern can execute the function when a condition is true or wait for the event when the condition is not true yet.

(Some scripts are dynamically loaded and do not execute as the event has then long ago been fired)

Currently i use:

```
if( myVar == 'pageInit'){ run the code which needs an inited page }
else{
  $(document).on('pageinit', function(){ run the code which needs an inited page }
}
```

Is there a pattern for handling this better?

Comment: There is no way to know when `myVar` has changed without checking it regularly or without triggering an event. Well, at least not in the "current" version: http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/11/Respond-to-change-with-Object-observe

Answer (score -1):

You can try

```
$(document).on('pageinit', function () { /* do stuff here */ }).trigger('pageinit');
```

That both sets it up for later triggers and also runs it the very first time after setup.

Comment: that would trigger('pageinit') when the page is not at init state yet, wouldnt it? My question is more how to do this or part. wait.on(x) OR (do it now when wait is passed)